# multiple self-hosted webapi on same server

Tags: asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

I want to host, mutiple self-hosted webapi's along with the web-site on the same machine / windows 2k8 server. For hosting the website I am using IIS. and for webapi's I would be using self-hosted webapi 2. How do I configure using self-hosted webapi, so that everything can work in sync on same server.

So lets say I will host the website at http://example.com/mysite and I will be hosting the webapi at http://example.com/apiws and http://example.com/apiui

I am using windows service for the configuration. This is how the web-api self hosting looks like as of now - for first webapi.

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(ServiceAddress);

        _config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        _config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi",
            "apiws/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        _server = new HttpSelfHostServer(_config);

        _server.OpenAsync().Wait();
    }
```

the configuration is almost same for the second server as well.

My question is having all of them working on the same port, is it possible? are there any issues which might arise? etc?

Comment: I dont get your question. You have hosted your application on `IIS` => Ok, You have seen an example of `selfhosting` => Ok, and now what is that you wanted to do next ?

Comment: Also, in your question => `but when I publish the app on server` => which server are you using ?

Comment: I am using IIS for publishing

Comment: Ok, so you are using `IIS`. Fine. What is that you want to do now ?

Comment: I want to host self hosted api on subdomain... may be @algos comment is right... may be i am just confured :( mixing webapi and hosting. Till now I was using webapi with MVC, so hosting together, now moved to angular so angular hosted in IIS, and webapi.. hmm

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to `self-host an webapi on subdomain`. It can be done. You can register `any Url` (provided no conflict) while self-hosting. Green Signal!

Comment: yup!! but how to do that, I am not finding any example around - googles somehow not helping this time

Comment: Ok, I will post an answer soon..

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. i am still waiting for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are confusing web-api with mvc.

MVC/IIS/websites needs hosting on domain on sub-domain.
webapi are just for listening to the request and providing the data response.